# AttributeError: module 'urllib.response' has no attribute 'status_code'

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

I'm new to python and working on a python project that checks username availability on Ubisoft.com. I'm trying to do this by entering a wordlist of possible usernames and letting the code check wether the site gives a 200- or a 404 status code, with 404 being a Unavailable username and 200 an Available username. When I run the code I get this traceback error message:

```
 File "C:\Users\Gibbo\OneDrive\Bureaublad\uPlay\usernamess.py", line 7, in <module>
   response = urllib.response.status_code("https://ubisoftconnect.com/en-US/profile/")
AttributeError: module 'urllib.response' has no attribute 'status_code'
```

And here's the code I've made

```
import datetime
import urllib.request
import urllib
import requests

url = "https://ubisoftconnect.com/en-US/profile/"
response = urllib.response.status_code("https://ubisoftconnect.com/en-US/profile/")

print(r.status_code)

url = 'https://ubisoftconnect.com/en-US/profile/'
available = "available.txt"
users = "usernames.txt"
now = datetime.datetime.now ()
if response.status_code == 200:
    print('Available')
elif response.status_code == 404:
    print('Unavailable')


def initialize():
    ascii_banner = pyfiglet.figlet_format("Made  By  Gxzs!!")
    print(ascii_banner)
    print(f"{count()} usernames detected")
    print("Press ENTER to begin checking")
    input("")
    check()
```

I'm fairly new to Python coding so I was not able to try out things myself

Answer (score 0):

urllib and requests are two separate packages, but you seem to be mixing them together. Here are how to get the status code from both of them on their own:

## Using urrllib

```py
import urllib.request

response = urllib.request.urlopen("https://ubisoftconnect.com/en-US/profile/")
status_code = response.getcode()
```

## Using requests

```py
import requests

response = requests.get("https://ubisoftconnect.com/en-US/profile/")
status_code = response.status_code
```